# gcov: 0% execution line error

Tags: trace, gcov

This is my first time dealing with "gcov", so I am trying to take it step by step. I am following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcov#Example) page, so I created a simple c file as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
int i;

for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
  if (i % 3 == 0)
    printf ("%d is divisible by 3\n", i);
  if (i % 11 == 0)
    printf ("%d is divisible by 11\n", i);
}

return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled the file:

```
gcc -Wall -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage test.c
```

Then I typed:

```
gcov test.c
```

Based on Wikipedia page, I should get something like:

```
88.89% of 9 source lines executed in file test.c
Creating test.c.gcov
```

However, what I am getting is:

```
File 'test.c'
Lines executed:0.00% of 7
test.c:creating 'test.c.gcov'
```

I don't know where is the problem. I am working on mac 10.10.4. When I type

```
gcc --version
```

I get:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-  include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

And when I type

```
gcov --version
```

I get:

```
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
LLVM version 3.6.0svn from Apple Clang 6.1.0 (build 602.0.53)
Optimized build.
Default target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Host CPU: x86-64
```

What I want actually is a tool that trace an execution of a program, the sequence of lines execution. I thought I may be able to achieve this through using "gcov".

Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute a.out before calling gcov.c as mentionned into the Wikipedia page :)

Comment: That's right. Please edit your answer though:  should be "before calling gcov test.c"